# Best design pattern for constant strings using Typescript (or Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, design-patterns

I have a view that has two modes - view and edit. I'm using angular so I will be using some directives to change the behavior of the page based on what mode it's in. I know it's common in C to #DEF some constant strings for use later. I was wondering if there is a good design pattern similar to this for use in JS. For example I will be doing something like:

```
    <input ng-if="mode==='edit'"></input>
```

Notice the string literal 'edit'

Comment: You can use [Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums like Satpal suggested are indeed a nice feature in typescript. However in you're case I would suggest to just use a boolean on you component (or if the mode is app-wide maybe a service).

Your html is also much cleaner, something like this:

```
<input ng-if="editMode"></input>
```

Comment: I think you are right. Enums seem to be a bit overkill in this situation. However I will definitely keep them in mind for the future!